# How to Stretch sap.m.ScrollContainer Over The Remaining Page Space in SAPUI5?

Tags: sapui5

have a page with disabled scrolling. page contains in it's content two sap.m.Table. one table for the sake of a fixed header. it contains just columns. other table inside a sap.m.ScrollContainer's content. it contains the items. use case is that the items do not fit the screen's height. without a scroll container the items would fall over the screen's bottom. page scrolling is still disabled. now i'd like that the scroll container jumps in. and it should exactly fill out the remaining page space between the first table in the page and the end of the page. until the bottom of the page. the end of the browser window. is there any work around to achieve that the sap.m.ScrollContainer goes automatically over the remaining space? without a scroll container's set to a specific height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

work around: wrap the site's content with a `sap.ui.layout.FixFlex`: set a pixel value to the `sap.ui.layout.FixFlex` property `minFlexSize`. the `sap.m.ScrollContainer` with the `sap.m.Table` goes into the `sap.ui.layout.FixFlex` aggregation `flexContent`. now the parent of the `sap.m.ScrollContainer` has a fixed height. therefore the `sap.m.ScrollContainer` can resize itself based on this.